# Trouble using JavaLexer and JavaParser using Antlr4.7 in python

Tags: java, python-3.x, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I downloaded Antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar file and also downloaded the javalexer.g4 and javaparser.g4 from github and used the following command:

```
java -jar ./antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 ./JavaLexer.g4
java -jar ./antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 ./JavaParser.g4
```

and got the JavaLexer.py and JavaParser.py file.
When I use the following code to generate AST from java source code, it give an error stating JavaLexer is not defined.

How do I import/use javalexer and javaparser in the following code?

```
from antlr4 import FileStream, CommonTokenStream, ParseTreeWalker

source = open("sample.java", "r", encoding="utf-8")
input_stream = InputStream(source.read())
print(input_stream)
lexer = JavaLexer(input_stream)
token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = JavaParser(token_stream)
tree = parser.compilationUnit()
print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

Comment: Let's first start at the Antlr tool call. I don't understand why you are using version 4.7.1 of the Antlr tool to generate a lexer, then version 4.6 of the Antlr tool to generate a parser. You can't just mix and match versions. But, why aren't you just using the latest, antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar?

Comment: sorry about the version 4.6 it was a typo.

Comment: The main problem being how to incorporate the javalexer and javaparser to the code.

Comment: In your main program (Main.py), replace that 1st line with `from antlr4 import *; from JavaLexer import *; from JavaParser import *;`, and place all your files in one directory. Then, `pip install antlr4-python3-runtime; java -jar antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar -encoding utf-8 -Dlanguage=Python3  *.g4; python Main.py`. See the code at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md#how-do-i-run-the-generated-lexer-andor-parser